# Vertically align select and number input in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, vertical-alignment

What can I do to have these inputs vertically aligned in Firefox?

It works in Chrome, Safari and Opera but not in Firefox (Version 57 tested in macOS, Windows and Linux Mint). Removing `type="number"` from the `input` solves it in Firefox but isn't something I want to remove.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label>First number <input class="form-control" type="number"></label>
  <label>
    Dropdown
    <select class="form-control">
      <option label="First option" selected="selected">
        First option
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to reset the `vertical-align` property on your `inline-block` *displayed* elements.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label>
     First number 
     <input class="form-control" type="number">
  </label>
  <label>
    Dropdown
    <select class="form-control">
      <option label="First option" selected="selected">
        First option
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
</body>
```